# USAGE message in BLAST search with python

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, blast

I am trying to filter a blast web search through the taxids of Bacteria and Achaea, this is my code:

```
from Bio.Blast.Applications import NcbiblastnCommandline
blastn_command = NcbiblastnCommandline(query="test.fasta", db="nt", outfmt="'7 qseqid sseqid qcovs qlen slen qstart qend'", out="blastn2.tab",remote=True,entrez_query="txid2157[ORGN] OR txid2[ORGN]")
stdout, stderr = blastn_command()
```

And I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
     stdout, stderr = blastn_command()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py", line 517, in __call__
     stdout_str, stderr_str)
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 1 from "blastn -out blastn2.tab -outfmt '7 qseqid sseqid qcovs qlen slen qstart qend' -query teste.fasta -db nt -entrez_query txid2157[ORGN] OR txid2[ORGN] -remote", message 'USAGE'
```

Answer (score 1):

TLDR

Double quote the `entrez_query` parameter (same as the `outfmt`).

The error is most probably caused by the fact, that the `entrez_query` parameter contain spaces and is not double quoted. As can be seen from the error message blast string, the `--entrez_query` is passed unquoted to the command-line (compare it with the `outfmt`, which you have double quoted).

The `USAGE` message is the first line of the actual error message produced by `blastn` that further contains following lines:

```
Error: Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: OR
Error:  (CArgException::eSynopsis) Too many positional arguments (1), the offending value: OR
```